# spartacus with hybris marketplace is feasible or not

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Hi Team can we use #spartacus with hybris marketplace as I can see everything mention on tutorial is for B2C or B2B. Could you please suggest way. #spartacus 'spartacus'

I want to set up marketplace where storefront could be driven by spartacus  as I was going through the tutorial and found everything was mentioned with b2c . As I will be using markeplace so it will have its own functionalities.

So is it feasible to use spartacus with marketplace ?  should I install marketplace and then follow the exact steps  mentioned in spartacus tutorial for installation.

Comment: Please add more details to your question so that other users can understand the question better and answer it.

Comment: Question has been elaborated now,

Comment: If you say "marketplace", do you mean an actual marketplace accelerator, or just marketplace as a concept?

Comment: Yeah , I have got answer at Spartacus Slack channel , market place is not supported as of now. Mirakle is in path but yet not defined.